# Bitcoin Core goes totally out of sync after pc crash

Tags: wallet

i've been trough 10+ days of syncing the Bitcoin Core and again mSigna wallet with Core...

downloaded bootstrap, then building blocks for Core to get synced was relatively fast, but mSigna has to build blocks for itself all over again while synced Core has to be running in the background. Its taking ageeees! way slower than the Core, especially last 100.000 blocks.)

And the 1.8 BTC are waiting in the unspent outputs on the blockchain cause i generated address for transaction from mSigna before when it was out of sync. (apparently you can do that in mSigna) just hoping when it gets synced i will see my coins in vault.

But the actual problem is that while mSigna was syncing(was at around 85%... 330.000+ blocks synced)  and the Core was normaly synced i suddenly got BSOD and computer restarted. Normaly first I opened bitcoin core to resume the process but now the Core is completely out of sync, and the blocks in bitcoin qt folder  are using 60 GB of space which means they are already builded..?
How can i tell the Core to use those synced blocks?
I will not open mSigna till the core is not synced again cause im afraid that msigna will restart aswell.
Thanks.

Comment: Did the crash make your system clock go out of wack?

Answer (score 1):

> Normaly first I opened bitcoin core to resume the process but now the Core is completely out of sync, and the blocks in bitcoin qt folder are using 60 GB of space which means they are already builded..?

The blocks on disk aren't really processed at all in the way you are thinking, what Bitcoin Core is doing when it is syncing is building a secondary database of its own which contains the state of the network. In a very unclean shutdown the database (known as the chainstate) will be corrupted and has to be rebuilt from the block files. There's no way to know exactly how it was damaged so it must be built entirely from scratch again. It is inconvenient but at least the blocks don't need to be downloaded again from the network again.

If you are getting frequent BSOD you might need to check your hardware or drivers.